# How to Display Today's Date in PHP Header

Tags: php, html, html-head

Total beginner php question:

**I want to put today's date in the header or my website.** In my header.php file I have the following code:

```
<?php @session_start(); 
$z = 1;
include 'functions.php';
$current_page_name = '"'.str_replace(".php","",basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])).'"';
?>

<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="index.php">
            <span>My Site</span>
            <img src="img/logo1.png" alt="logo" />
            <p>Tagline</p>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="about.php">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    XXXXXXXXXXXX
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

From googling, I think I want to insert the following code into the XXXXXXXXXXXX placeholder above`<p><b><?php echo "Today's Date ".date("d/M/Y"); ?></b></p>`.

Is this the correct approach? Wanted to check here before I started breaking things; any advice super appreciated!

Comment: So, which part of that are you having a problem with?

Comment: You seem to have a complete solution to your problem stated in the question already. If you want to know whether or not the quality of your solution is sufficient, you can ask the question in the [code review communtiy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which is made for questions like yours.

Comment: Didn't know that community existed; this question is probably better there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so my only advice is: If you want to display the current date for your user: Don't use php. Its more work to get the users timezone and display the date then just displaying it via javascript.

if you replace your XXXXXXXXXXXX part with the following script it should help you out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(new Date().toLocaleDateString());
</script>
```